# reCAPTCHA v2 with HTML5 Dialog .showModal() method

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, recaptcha, html5dialog

Google's reCAPTCHA v2 displays layering problems when included in a HTML5 dialog triggered with `.showModal()`. The challenge element with the question and the images is layered underneath the dialog instead of on top.

Try this demo in [a browser which natively supports the HTML5 dialog](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog), such as Chrome:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/karlhorky/b3hjdqeL/)

[image: Broken reCAPTCHA in HTML5 dialog]

The offending code is the `document.body.appendChild(a.P)` in [the reCAPTCHA JavaScript](https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20151117130340/recaptcha__de.js), which appends the challenge div to the document body. I've thought about monkey-patching this to append to the `dialog` instead, but this is also not an ideal solution.

One workaround is to use the `.show()` method instead of the `.showModal()` method:

[Workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/karlhorky/b3hjdqeL/7/)

Is there a better solution to this? @google Can this be fixed in reCAPTCHA itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking the dialog using `.show()` and mimicking the styling of the `.showModal()` method seems to be the best solution for now:

http://jsfiddle.net/karlhorky/b3hjdqeL/9/

Unless Google updates reCAPTCHA for use inside `<dialog>`s, this is the cleanest solution I've come up with.